# Working with Microsoft SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb.net-2010

I am attempting to use code like the following

```
Sub newDatabase()
    Dim command as New sqlcommand
End Sub
```

Unfortunately sqlcommand isn't recognized by my vb.NET 2010. Is there anything I have to do before using that line?

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported the namespace `System.Data.SqlClient` at the top of your code?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

...
Sub newDatabase()
   Dim command as New SqlCommand()
   ...
End Sub
```

Comment: This was the exact answer I needed. Thanks